# Unable to run a project using gnome-builder

Tags: gnome, gedit, flatpak, gnome-builder

I recently installed gnome-builder using flatpak. But when I try to run the gedit project it shows the error `ide-run-manager[    2]:  WARNING: Not a make build system` . But it just compiles fine. I am new to using builder.